# Why AngularJS ng-bind not updating pushed array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to push string into array and live update in view. It is working in expression but not working in ng-bind. Please help me find out why?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app=“app”>
        <div ng-controller="testController">
           <div ng-bind="fruit"></div>
           <div>{{fruit}}</div>
           <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.fruit = ['apple'];

    $scope.add = function() {
        var a = 'banana';
        $scope.fruit.push(a);
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat to print all value from your array

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.fruit = ['apple'];

    $scope.add = function() {
        var a = 'banana';
        $scope.fruit.push(a);
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="testController">
           <div ng-bind="fruit"></div>
           <div ng-repeat="item in fruit track by $index">{{item}}</div>
           <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bind` is not working because you change the value of `fruit` outside of `digest` cycle of your angular app.

To update the variable in `ng-bind` use `$scope.apply()`.

You can also use `ng-repeat` as suggested by [sumit chauhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7654873/sumit-chauhan).

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.fruit = ['apple'];

    $scope.add = function() {
       var a = 'banana';
       $scope.fruit.push(a);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in fruit track by $index">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I use apply to update the variable in ng-bind? I do not want to use expression to out put fruit to avoid page refresh empty {{}}.